# String modification in XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xslt

What is the equivalent XSLT code for the Java code below?

```
    if (s.length() > 11) {
        return s.substring(0, 8) + s.substring(9, 12);
    }
    if (s.length() == 11) {
        return s;
    }
    return s;
```

I have to so same above check on a field called: `Lkup_CODE`:

```
<Identifier>
    <xsl:value-of select="Lkup_CODE" />
</Identifier>
```

Regards,

Chaitu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an imperative (and discouraged) solution try the following:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="string-length(Lkup_CODE) &gt; 11">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($Lkup_CODE, 1, 8), substring(Lkup_CODE, 10, 3))"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="string-length(Lkup_CODE) = 11">
    <xsl:value-of select="Lkup_CODE"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="Lkup_CODE"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: So...why do you think this should be discouraged? I mean except from skipping the second `xsl:when`, which could be skipped in the java code provided as well... I don't see why this should be discouraged.

Comment: How it works without defining variable string-length(Lkup_CODE)?

Comment: user, I'm assuming that you have a `Lkup_CODE` element in your XML, and that it is in scope during the processing (just like the `Identifier` example). Else just use an variable to select it `<xsl:variable name="Lkup_CODE" select="/path/to/Lkup_CODELement"/>` and precede `Lkup_CODE` with a `$` to use the variable instead of the element.

Comment: @Tobias, Because it promotes unnecessary use of imperative idioms in a declarative programming language. Whenever possible use templates instead of `<xsl:if>`, `<xsl:for-each>`, `<xsl:choose>`, etc. There are valid cases for control-flow statements in XSLT, but I don't think this is one of them.

Comment: I think this is exactly the kind of operation where I'd rather use an imperative construct... It is just a simple operation on a string, why would I write three templates for that...

Comment: I would probably write something in the middle ground. Two templates, with conditional calls to `apply-template`. Not as short as the imperative solution, but clean and reusable.

Comment: why substring index starts from 1 in xslt not 0?

Comment: in your answer you quoted (10,3) is it (10,12)?

Comment: User, check helderdaroch [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24614586/664577) the index starts from 1 (language decision), and the third parameter is the amount of characters to retrieve (you want 3 characters starting from the 10th position).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a test case. Assuming you use a source such as:

```
<Codes>
    <Lkup_CODE>01234567:ABCDEF</Lkup_CODE> <!-- string length > 11  -->
    <Lkup_CODE>01234567:A</Lkup_CODE>      <!-- string length < 11  -->
    <Lkup_CODE>01234567:AB</Lkup_CODE>     <!-- string length == 11 -->
</Codes>
```

You can deal with each case using a different template for `Lkup_CODE`, matching the string length of its contents. For example, this XPath expression will match a code that is exactly 11 characters long (the last one):

```
Lkup_CODE[string-length(.)=11]
```

You could use a single template for the equality case and the less-than, since they return the same result. You could have different ones in case you need to deal differently with each case:

```
<xsl:template match="Lkup_CODE[string-length(.)=11]">
    <Identifier>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </Identifier>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Lkup_CODE[string-length(.) &lt; 11]">
    <Identifier>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </Identifier>
</xsl:template>
```

For the *greater-than* case, you have to deal with substrings. In XPath the string starts in 1, and the `substring()` function includes the first position and the *number of characters to extract after that* instead of a position, as in Java. This would be the Java / XPath mapping for your functions:

- Chars  1 to  8 in Java: `s.substring(0, 8)`  == in XPath: `substring(s, 1, 8)`
- Chars 10 to 12 in Java: `s.substring(9, 13)` == in XPath: `substring(s, 10, 3)`

This template will deal with that condition:

```
<xsl:template match="Lkup_CODE[string-length(.) &gt; 11]">
    <Identifier>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(.,1,8),substring(., 10,3))"/>
    </Identifier>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is a full stylesheet for the test case I included at the beginning of this answer:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="Codes">
        <Result>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Result>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Lkup_CODE[string-length(.)=11]">
        <Identifier>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </Identifier>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Lkup_CODE[string-length(.) &lt; 11]">
        <Identifier>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </Identifier>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Lkup_CODE[string-length(.) &gt; 11]">
        <Identifier>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(.,1,8),substring(., 10,3))"/>
        </Identifier>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It will produce the following result:

```
<Result>
    <Identifier>01234567ABC</Identifier> <!-- modified because > 11 -->
    <Identifier>01234567:A</Identifier>  <!-- unmodified because < 11 -->
    <Identifier>01234567:AB</Identifier> <!-- unmodified because = 11 -->
</Result>
```